# prove the projection transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P_z : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$
>   be the function which orthogonally projects onto the $x$-$y$ linearity 
>   plane (that is, the set of vectors
>   $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3$ with $z = 0$). Is $P_z$ linear? If so,
>   prove it; if not, explain why not.

I understand I have to show that the linear map has the 3 properties:

1. $P_z(0)=0$
2. $P_z(u+w)=P_z(u) + P_z(w)$
3. $P_z(cu)=cP_z(u)$

But, how to do it in this problem?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Simple projection functions are always linear. You can easily veify the conditions of linearity intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection takes any vector $(x, y, z)$ and gives back the vector $(x, y, 0)$. Now you just check. Take vectors, do the vector operation then apply the transformation. Then try again, byt apply the transformation first, *then* do the vector operations. See that you get the same answer.

For instance, $P_z(cu) = cP_z(u)$: Take a vector $u = (x, y, z)$ and a real number $c$. Then $$
P_z(cu) = P_z(c(x, y, z)) = P_z((cx, cy, cz)) = (cx, cy, 0)
$$
while
$$
cP_z(u) = cP_z((x, y, z)) = c(x, y, 0) = (cx, cy, 0)
$$
and we see that they are the same. Now do a similar thing for sum of two vectors (zero vector comes for free from this one by picking $c = 0$), and you're done.